# Tableview cut the last row but correct after back

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have one tableview that cut off in the last row of the cell. But when i click one cell, and click back from the next viewcontroller, my tableview is correctly shown all the cell.

Whast wrong with my tableview?

I set my tableview like this in home controller:

in ViewDidLoad:

```
 self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

   override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    self.myTableView.frame = self.view.bounds
}
```

and present the next view controller like this:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
```

and navigate back like this:

```
@IBAction func back(){
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Comment: what are the constraint you set for myTableView?

Comment: hi @sschunara my tableview constraint: trailing, leading to superview. bottom space to bottom layout, top space to top layout equals -20

Comment: Try set bottom layout to view don't bottow layout guide.

Answer (score 0):

use autolayout. set `top,bottom,leading and trailing` constraints to it. and don't set frame of tableview like `self.view.bounds`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in `viewWillAppear` Method..

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    super.viewWillAppear(animated) // No need for semicolon

    self.myTableView.frame = self.view.bounds
}
```